# ¿Por que jQuery no funciona al importarlo en un proyecto de Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap

Estoy queriendo utilizar el template SB-ADMIN2 de bootstrap en un proyecto de angular y cuando levanto mi aplicacion, las animaciones y los dashboards no aparecen. Los archivos js estan alojados en assets y los importe en los scripts de angular pero aun asi no reconoce las animaciones y tampoco se muestran en el html

este es mi **angular.json**

```
  "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/diversidad-front",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",

              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/js/sb-admin-2.min.js",
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js",
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js",
              "src/assets/bootstrapTheme/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"
            ]
          }
```

este es mi **packaje.json**

````
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }, ```

Asi se ve mi aplicacion cuando levanto el servidor
````

Answer (score 0):

Configuré un proyecto y seguí estos pasos:

1. Copiar las carpetas css, js y vendor  al directorio assets.
2. Agregar estilos y scripts al archivo angular.json

```js
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/sb-admin-2.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/sb-admin-2.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js",
              "src/assets/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"
            ]
```

3. Copiar el contenido del index.html del SB Admin y pegarlo en el app.component.html de Angular. Quitar las referencias a los scripts y css.

Con eso ya queda funcionando la demo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]